# How-To: Editing Visual Studio Bookmarks

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Sometimes, like in a config, you add in bookmarks to areas, and then you add or remove code, and the bookmarks are no longer valid.

Is there a way to edit a bookmark in Visual Studio, to change the line number, or move the bookmark to another line? Perhaps some sort of add-in, or Extension, that allows moving them?

Or perhaps there's a file created somewhere on my machine for those bookmarks, that I can edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the functionality you want is not available. The bookmarks are stored as binary data in the project's .suo file. In Visual Studio 2015, the line number of the bookmark can't be changed. If you go to `View` > `Other Windows` > `Bookmark Window` (shortcut Ctrl+K, Ctrl+W) there will be a dialog which allows you to make a few changes.

*We can't do what you want with this interface,* but we can:

- Disable single or multiple bookmarks (without deleting)
- Change the sort order of bookmarks
- Name bookmarks
- Name folders and organize bookmarks

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that the default interface is rather... lacking. I am hoping that some genius out there has come up with a VS extension that allows more functionality (like how Tabs Studio gives you a lot better method for dealing with filename tabs).